# Different scale of basemap after exporting to PDF/Image

Tags: print-composer, scale, qgis-openlayers-plugin, basemap, qgis-2.8

After creating and exporting my map to pdf/tif obviously there are different scales of the basemap in the exported file compared to the map I created in the printcomposer. See pictures...

I am using QGIS 2.8.1 on a windows 7 (64bit) machine. For the basemap I use basemap.at (WMS). The CRS is the same for all layers (WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator).

Created Map in Print composer at 1:950000:
[image]

And what I get after exporting it to pdf is a more detailed basemap...
[image]

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Same issue with OpenLayers plugin and Google Streets.

Comment: It seems to be an old and known problem http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827 however it has not been solved  yet.

Comment: The print problem of OpenLayers plugin layers is a different issue than printing WMS layers.